# gnuplot "previous parametric function not fully specified" when trying to plot 3d shapes from 2 datafiles

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot 2 curves from 2 datafiles in 3d style.
Here's my gnuplot program:

```
set parametric
set xr [-2:2]
set yr [-2:2]
set zr [-2:2]
set datafile separator comma
splot "a.csv" u 2,3,4 w lines, \
      "b.csv" u 2,3,4 w lines
```

but I get this message: `"test.plt" line 7: previous parametric function not fully specified`

My datafiles:
a.csv

```
504, 0, -1, -1
505, 0, -1,  1
506, 0,  1,  1
507, 0, -1,  1
```

and b.csv

```
504, -1, -1, 0
505, -1,  1, 0
506,  1,  1, 0
507, -1,  1, 0
```

The first column is just a sequence number while the other columns contain the x, y, z coordinates.
I think I have to use the parametric option to plot the curves, because when I don't use it I get these points instead of 2 curves:
[image: plot w/o parametric]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you have to use `set parametric`?

Just use:

```
reset session
set xr [-2:2]
set yr [-2:2]
set zr [-2:2]
set datafile separator comma
splot "a.csv" u 2:3:4 w lines, \
      "b.csv" u 2:3:4 w lines
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Ah thanks, I see my fault: I used commas to separate the column numbers in the splot command. When I use colons in the splot command I get the correct results.